# Which ClassNotFoundException to use?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am currently working on a Laravel project and I have a bit of code where I want to throw an exception if the class of the given type cannot be found.

```
$className = $type . 'Field';

if (!class_exists($className))
{
    // Throw exception
}
```

However my IDE (IntelliJ) is giving me auto-complete for 3 different classes belonging to different packages that all have the same name.

- `Prophecy\Exception\Doubler\ClassNotFoundException`
- `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException`
- `PhpSpec\Exception\Fracture\ClassNotFoundException`

What is the difference between these and which one should I use in this scenario and why?

Comment: Well it depends greatly on the context of your code. Why do you have undefined classes? Is it because a user (dev, admin, whatever) can change `$className`? What do you want to do when the class is not found?

Comment: The type is dependent on the database. I am using the presenter pattern and trying to dynamically select which class to use to display the data. I want to have this validation to give off an error if somehow the database value becomes corrupted or out of sync with the application files.

Comment: Sounds good. Perhaps you should make the check when writing to the database in stead. Then you won't have the overhead at runtime when running your user code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The only thing remaining that is confusing me is method definition for `ClassNotFoundException` differs from the other exceptions I am used to throwing. It requires an extra parameter `ErrorException $previous` which I am not sure what its use is for since I only want to throw the one exception and not a chain of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException`.

Other two Exception handlings are for PhpSpec (Testing) and Prophecy (a mocking framework for phpspec).

Since you are trying to throw an exception for `ClassNotFound`, you should be using the Symfony Exception Handler.